# Netlify installs bibtex-ruby gem but then fails on require 'bibtex' in script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, netlify

I have the above build problem with my site. The bibtex-ruby gem seems to install just fine, but then my build script's require statement fails to find the library. The script works locally. The error is:

12:01:28 PM: /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bibtex (LoadError)
12:01:28 PM:    from /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'

Comment: How did you install them gem? Where are you running `require` from? The most likely mistake is that you've only installed it locally (`gem install ...`), but need to explicitly include it as a dependency of a project - i.e. add it to the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Comment: It's part of the Gemfile – I can see it being installed in the Deploy log on Netlify:

12:00:56 PM: Fetching bibtex-ruby 4.4.7
12:00:56 PM: Installing bibtex-ruby 4.4.7

Comment: What is "my build script"? How is it executing?

Comment: You can set a build command on Netlify, which I've set to a script, build.sh. This script writes Jekyll code based on a bibtex file and then runs jekyll build

Comment: I'm not familiar with netlify build commands. At a guess, however, I would say that it is executing outside of your `bundler` environment. You could try adding the gem dependency inline, within the script, like this: https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_in_a_single_file_ruby_script.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add your /Gemfile and /Gemfile.lock to your project root folder. This will tell Netlify what to install for your project. You should not have to run a shell command to install the gems on Netlify. The Gemfile and Gemfile.lock together give Netlify the information for your setup.